# Deploying NodeJS in Render (Web Service) getting " SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??=' "

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, render.com

I am using NodeJS and MongoDB atlas to create my own API for my online portfolio. I have tested it locally and it's working fine. So I decided to deploy it and test it in 'Render(Web Services)' because it is free.

I deployed it and the build was successful.
[actual log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Dl4M.png)

However, I got this error log after:
[actual error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kL13.png)

Error log:

> /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/find_and_modify.js:33
> Aug 30 01:46:27 PM          options.includeResultMetadata ??= false;

I have tried searching for an answer, but I can't seem to find one. But I am still working on it because I badly need this for my online portfolio.

I don't know how to fix this. Please help! Any idea? :<

Answer (score 0):

maybe you've solved it by now but i had the same issue and it turns out that i was using a NodeJS version that did not support the '??=' operator.

As you can see in the table almost at the bottom on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment) the support for the '??=' operator was added in NodeJS 15.0.0. Apparently on your development machine you are running a newer NodeJS version, and on your production machine you are running an older NodeJS version.

Upgrading the NodeJS version on your production machine should solve this error :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the engines in `package.json`:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mongodb": "^6.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1"
  },
    "engines": {

    "node": ">=14 <18.17.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this version please. Change package.json in mongodb version;

```
"mongodb": "^4.16.0",
```